# Headers not set using Ext.Ajax.request form upload

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6, extjs6-modern

I want to upload a file using `Ext.Ajax.request`. Therefore I add the id of the file-input-field (`form: formId`). I also want to add some headers (`Accept`, `Authorization`, ...) to the request, which works when I don't add the `form` parameter. However when the form parameter is set my headers will be ignored for whatever reason.

I use ExtJs 6.2 modern.

How can I add headers when a form parameter is set to the request?

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
            cors: true,
            useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
            method: 'POST',
            url: someUrl,
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': someString,
                'usertoken': someString
            },
            params: {
                name: fileName,
                override: false
            },
            isUpload: true,
            form: formId
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

When you make a request with the form option, its not actually an Ajax request, and as such you can't pass extra headers.

From [Docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.data.Connection.html)

> File uploads are not performed using normal "Ajax" techniques, that is they are not performed using XMLHttpRequests. Instead the form is submitted in the standard manner with the DOM  element temporarily modified to have its target set to refer to a dynamically generated, hidden  which is inserted into the document but removed after the return data has been gathered.

Comment: This is terrible. What happens if you need to XSRF-TOKEN?